# Galaxy S screen glowing in locked state as if some one tried to unlock it, even with out touching it

Tags: lock-screens

My mobile is working fine till yesterday, but suddenly I observed that when I lock it and keep  it aside, I can see that the screen is glowing as if some one tried to unlock it. This is happening quite often. Can some one please explain me what is the problem and the solution for that pbm.

Comment: Is it glowing with the screen being black or is the screen actually on and showing the lockscreen?

Comment: This looks like it's a LCD model and the backlight stays on with the LCD showing black (or being unpowered). This is most probably a bug with the firmware, so look for an official update or install an aftermarket firmware like [cyanogenmod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S:_Full_Update_Guide)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings, Wireless networks, WiFi settings then uncheck NOTIFY ME FOR OPEN NETWORKS.  This solved the problem for me :)